# Reverse accessor clash between Django's auto generated fields

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations

I have a base table that I want to extend in a couple different apps installed in my project. My issue is that I usually want the table to be named the same thing despite what app it is installed in. These apps all live in the same PostGres database, in separate schemas:

```
#App1
ParentModel(models.Model):
    #fields

#App2
ChildModel(ParentModel):
    #fields

#App3
ChildModel(ParentModel):
    #fields
```

When I try to run makemigrations, it complains about a reverse accessor clash between the auto generated 'childmodel_ptr' fields. It suggests adding a 'related_name' argument. However obviously I cannot do that as this field is being auto generated by Django. Is there a mechanism by which I can supply a 'related_name' argument to whatever django machinery is generating that field?

Answer (score 0):

[I failed to RTFM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#s-multi-table-inheritance)

Overriding the field and adding a `related_name` did the trick.